Android. How to disable multiple selection of files via intent?
I'm trying to select file with intent Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. Here is my code:
ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> launcher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument(), uri -> {
    if (uri != null) {
     
    }
});

And then:
launcher.launch(mimeTypes);

This works, however I would like to only allow the user to select one file. But at the moment, when the file explorer opens, the user can select multiple files. I would like to disable multiple selection, is this possible?
Please, help me.

you need to add
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false);

on your intent ie setting multiple to false
here is a snippet
ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> launcher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument(), uri -> {
    if (uri != null) {
     
    }
});

// method to launch the file picker with single selection
private void openDocumentPicker(String[] mimeTypes) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
// Disabling  multiple selection
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false); 

    launcher.launch(intent);
}

// Usage and setting the mimetype
String[] mimeTypes = {"image/*", "application/pdf"}; 
openDocumentPicker(mimeTypes);


Do I understand correctly that ActivityResultLauncher should accept Intent, not  String[] ?

re read the instructions correctly
